# Is is valid to declare an inline element as block?

Tags: html, css

I passed a style sheet with the following to the W3C validator and it passed:

```
a {
  display: block;
}
```

So want to make sure, is it valid markup to use an inline element as a block one?
I know it will work but is it valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's completely valid. And useful too.

One small note (since the above answer is very short), this method of styling normally inline elements as block elements is quite common. For example, when creating a horizontal navigation menu from a list, you'll often see `<a>` elements styled with `display:block` in order for the links to be able to take up the full width and height of the parent list item.

Comment: It should be noted that it doesn't change the rules, for instance the opposite (`display:inline`) will not allow you to put a `<div>` inside a `<p>`

Comment: and this is what i want actually for items in menu instead of having to wrap the a tags inside divs which just doesn't make sense to me

Comment: i have another question...is it valid also to use text-align to center two inline DIVs or is it considered a hack???

Comment: That's fine too. As the MDN says, "The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. text-align does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content." So if the content is inline, then you can use text-align on it (without guilt!).

Comment: but in w3schools it explicitly says it's used to align text in an element...that's why i'm hesitant...

Comment: Well first, don't go by w3schools. Use https://developer.mozilla.org instead. Second, text-align is used to align inline elements within a parent block level container.

Comment: one last question...is it also valid to use the line-height on parent and vertical-align middle on child inline div to center the child vertically???

Comment: Vertical alignment is more tricky. Take a look at http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/ to get an idea of the various methods.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's valid but also you can use `inline-block` to use an inline element while keeping the block properties.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer to the OPs question.

Comment: true. Somehow the comment button doesn't always display on my page.

Comment: +1 and welcome, don't get upset and don't be lost, it's a nice place to learn so many things :-)

Comment: I know, it helped me so many times I thought I just had to contribute too. Thanks for the welcome :-)

Comment: @SheikhHeera Nice little edit there ;) Removed my downvote, +1'd.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is valid.

There are elements, as you know, that are inline or block by default. But it is completely valid to then go and override this in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is valid. However, if you *really* don't want to do that, you could wrap the `a` in a `div`. That would be useless though, because it is completely valid; that's why the `display` attribute is there.

Answer (score 0):

The style sheet is valid, in the sense that it conforms to the CSS specifications. This is a purely formal thing. In CSS, the selector `a` has no special meaning, it is just an identifier; CSS has no information about the meaning of `a` in HTML, such as being an inline element, and the style sheet could in fact be used to style an XML document, where `a` means something completely different.

HTML validity, on the other hand, does not depend on CSS at all. It is a formal thing about markup, and style sheets aren’t markup.

Whether it is “valid” in some other, informal sense (like “good practice” or “useful” or “conforming to a style guide”) is a different issue, and a debate issue rather than a technical question. Anyway, it is common usage to set `display: block` on an `a` element to make it possible to set its dimensions the way we can do for blocks (e.g., to make a link fill a table cell).